# How to control children of LinearLayout in a ListView?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-arrayadapter

I just set up my ArrayAdapter to convertView to my favor , but now I wonder how to control the children of the LinearLayouts am using in that listview , lets say I have a TextView in the Linearlayout , I want to call setText , but I don't know how , or maybe I have a button which I want to call setOnClickListener , I don't know how !

Here is my getView code :

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.normal_row, parent , false);
        }
        switch(position){
        case(0):
            // here is where my first LinearLayout goes , containing an Image and Switch which I need to program in onCheckedChangeListener ...
            convertView = (LinearLayout) inf.inflate(R.layout.row_switch, parent,false);

            break;

        case(1)
        // here I need to set the Text for the following two options on some basis , they are both linearLayouts containing a single textView which I want to call setText for each case  1 and 2.
             break;
            case(2)

        }
```

Comment: Mixing your layouts in ListView can be dangerous. convertView might be a layout inflated from R.layout.row_switch, but you might handle it as if it would be an R.layout.normal_row...

Comment: The text you want to set should be somehow related to the array backing the ArrayAdapter. With the position you should be able to get the item of the array in question, and could use it for setting the text. You can also use Tags to store data related to a widget, that you can use in event handlers...

Comment: I don't understand well , but normal_row is same as row_switch , they are both LinearLayouts with different children , but I don't even know how to handle these guys !

Comment: Can you describe your list in more details? What rows does it have? Are there several types of rows?

Comment: I got my answer down , thanks everybody !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextView textview = (TextView) convertView.findById(R.id.txt); 
text.setText("textview");

Button btn  = (Button) convertView.findById(R.id.btn); 

btn.setTag(textview); 

btn.setOnClickListener(...)
{
   onClick(..){
      TextView t = (Textview)btn.getTag():
      t.setText("new value")

   }
}
```

i suggest you to look at the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738888/i-have-a-listview-where-each-row-contains-an-edittext-field-and-textview-what/13741285#13741285) which i replied before.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your normal_row layout has a TextView in it with the id @id/my_text_view. Then you would set the text like

```
TextView view = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
view.setText("Some text");
```

You can access anything in the layout you've inflated by its id in a similar way.

One thing to note though is there seem to be two types of views that you're inflating. Let's say that you try to use the code I gave you, but `my_text_view` is only in normal_row. Then if you've inflated the `row_switch` view, the findViewById() will return null because it can not find a view with the given id.

Answer (score 0):

Use onItemClick and find your view by the view that the OnItemClickListener provides you!

For example: `mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

        }

    });`
```

By the passed View find your textview or your button inside every listView children.

Example: `TextView tempTextView = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);`

The id of the textview is the one you assigned to it in your inflated layout for every row!

Comment: Thank you , but I got my answer :)